# Is it possible to setup my own DDNS with the help of a VPS?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, vps, ddns

I am using Digital Ocean's Linux VPS, say, hosting my own domain `example.com` on a fixed ip address: `198.211.10.10` ...

At home, I have a broadband internet service, sharing to two PCs via a Wifi router. The IP address assigned by my broadband provider is usually random. Now, I'd like to add a third Linux box at home, forwarding port 80 of the Wifi router to it.

Is it possible to setup my own DDNS (without subscribe to service like DynDNS)? Such that other people from the internet can access my new Linux box by:

```
 http://home.example.com
```

If yes, what software are required on my VPS and/or home Linux box?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to do this, and there is almost certainly more then 1 route.

You might want to have a look at "[dd-server](http://dd-server.sourceforge.net/)" which purports to by a Dynamic DNS server.  (This would work with dd-client I expect)

You might want to "roll your own" using HTTP, a bit of php (or whatever code) and combine it with an easy to update database (something like MyDNS or PowerDNS which read straight out of a database) along with a cron script to do an http get might be another solution.